# Solving matrix equation $X^{-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n D_i X A_i$

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-equations

Does anybody know an algorithm to solve the following matrix equation?

$$X^{-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n D_i X A_i$$

where $D_i$s are diagonal and $A_i$s are symmetric matrices.

It would be great to have an efficient numerical algorithm with a convergence guarantee. As Suvrit suggested, one can use Newton method that is efficient. The question is if Newton method without line-search has convergence guarantee or not. Because, I would like to avoid line-search if possible.

Comment: what is an algorithm for you? Surely people know how to solve systems of polynomial equations, and this problem is a particular instance of such a general problem.

Comment: Rewrite the equation as $1=\sum_iXD_iXA_i$. Make it linear by splitting the variable: $1=\sum_iXD_iYA_i$. This is a linear equation in the tensor argument $X\otimes Y$ and can be solved using the Gauss algorithm. Intersect the affine solution space with the diagonal $X=Y$ and finally with the set of invertibles.

Comment: @Anton a naive implementation of your suggestion leads to needlessly increasing the dimensionality of the problem (and hence, massively increasing the running time). It is numerically easier to just run a Newton iteration for $0 = F(X) :=\sum_i XD_iXA_i - I$ (by considering $F(X+E)$, as is usual)...

Comment: @Dima I would like to have an efficient numerical algorithm like Newton method that Suvrit suggested. I would implement Newton method to see if it converges. I like to have a method with a convergence guarantee.

Comment: What if you computed the $\min_{X}\sum_i \mbox{Trace}(D_iXA_i)$ subject to $\begin{bmatrix} 
\sum_{i}D_iXA_i & I \\
I & X
\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0$ and $X\succeq I$. You might want to try your luck for a particular instance of the problem.